# How to move files into corresponding folder using Batch files

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
for %%j in (*.pdf) do (
    java -jar pdfbox-app-1.7.1.jar PDFToImage %%j
)

if exist *.jpg (
    for %%i in (*.jpg) do (
        mkdir %%~ni
        tesseract %%i %%~ni.txt
        move %%i %%~ni
        move %%~ni.txt %%~ni
    )
)
```

So I have this command which basically converts:

1. Converts pdf file into jpg files.
2. For all the JPG files it  makes corresponding folder.
3. It uses tesseract software to convert the image file into text file.
4. Move the JPG files into the corresponding folder that I just created (**works**).
5. Move the text files into the corresponding folder that I just created (Doesn't Work).

Can anyone tell me how I can make it so that it would move the text files into the corresponding folders just like I did to image files?  So in the end for each folder, it would contain both image file and text file. Thank you !

Comment: When you say "Doesn't Work", what is the problem? Trying your batch file with some dummy files (without the `tesseract` step) works fine for me.

Comment: hmmmm for some reason it doesn't work for me. So if you do 
for %%i in (*.txt) do move %%i %%~ni  does it move every text file into the corresponding name folder for you?

Comment: oh.. ok it works when I do it separately, but for some reason if I add 
the separate command appended to the original command it doesn't move the text files into the folder and just terminates.... QQ I could technically make separate executable file, but I want to have it done within one..

Comment: If I use your script with only the `tesseract` line removed, and using some dummy `.jpg` and `.txt` files, it works fine. Peter Wright below already suggested a possible cause, but if you post the error message or explain otherwise what "Doesn't Work" actually means, then it might be possible to determine the exact issue you are looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not tell tesseract to put the file in the correct place in the first place so you no longer have to move it :-)

Also, you really should put quotes around your file names, just in case you run into a file with spaces in the name.

```
@echo off
for %%j in (*.pdf) do (
    java -jar pdfbox-app-1.7.1.jar PDFToImage "%%j"
)

if exist *.jpg (
    for %%i in (*.jpg) do (
        mkdir "%%~ni"
        tesseract "%%i" "%%~ni\%%~ni.txt"
        move "%%i" "%%~ni"
    )
)
```

If, for some odd reason, tessereact insists on putting the file in the current folder, then  change your current folder.

```
@echo off
for %%j in (*.pdf) do (
    java -jar pdfbox-app-1.7.1.jar PDFToImage "%%j"
)

if exist *.jpg (
    for %%i in (*.jpg) do (
        mkdir "%%~ni"
        pushd "%%~ni"
        tesseract "..\%%i" "%%~ni.txt"
        popd
        move "%%i" "%%~ni"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!  How did I not think of that.. Your first suggestion worked perfectly fine !!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that tesseraxt is being very clever and launching the actual conversion as a separate process, then terminating. The result would therefore be that the .txt file may not be written when batch tries to move it.

personally, I'd try (air code)

```
...
    tesseract %%i %%~ni.txt
    call :transfer %%~ni
...
...
goto :eof
:transfer
setlocal
set count=6
:tloop
if exist %1.txt move %1.jpg %1&move %1.txt %1&goto :eof
set /a count-=1
:: wait 1 second...
if %count% gtr 0 ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul &goto tloop
echo could not find %1.txt after 6 seconds...
goto :eof
```